# What is the benefit of larger pointers on 64-bit systems?

Tags: c++, pointers, 64-bit, c++builder

I am trying to understand 64-bit compiling, so I did a little test in C++ Builder:

```
  int i = 12345;
  ShowMessage(i);
  int *pi = &i;
  ShowMessage(sizeof(pi));


  Largeint li = 9223372036854775807;
  ShowMessage(li);
  Largeint *pli = &li;
  ShowMessage(sizeof(pli));
```

When I compile this program as 64 bit, the  size of the *pointer* increases to 8 bytes (64 bits).

What is the advantage of the increased pointer size?

Comment: A `4`-byte pointer can only address ~4GB of memory. That can run out fast in a modern program.

Comment: The size of a pointer usually just reflects the underlying system. If you're on a 32-bit system, you get 32-bit pointers, and on a 64-bit system you get 64-bit pointers. It really doesn't make sense to have anything else.

Comment: Except of course that many 64 bits systems have 32 bits subsystems. That means a 4 GB limit per 32 bit process, but the total system memory can then be much more.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A **pointer** can hold the **address** of a single byte in **memory**. Based on its size you can calculate the maximum number of different values a given pointer can store.

With a pointer of **4 bytes** (*32 bits*) you are limited to address only **4GB** of memory, since:

```
2^32 = 4294967296
```

On the other hand, a **8 bytes** (*64 bit*) pointer is able to address a much wider range of **17179869184GB** theoretically:

```
2^64 = 18446744073709551616
```

This are **16EB** (exabytes).

In **practice**, it is much **less** than that, because of limitations on most processors and the physical size of the memory etc.

You can read more on this topic here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#Limitations_of_practical_processors

Comment: "With a pointer of 4 bytes (32 bits) you are limited to address only 4GB of memory" good answer. But Why is there this limit ?

Comment: I added a little explanation on the top of my answer. is it clear now? with 32bits (4bytes) you have "only" 4294967296 possible values. So you can address 4294967296 different bytes in memory, which is 4gb

Comment: we need more memory,for more addressing.

Comment: more memory is always nice :), but even with my 8GB a 32bit pointer would be not sufficient.

Comment: @İsmailKocacan you don't even necessarily need the physical RAM to benefit from this - in any modern OS, all your process memory is virtualised. you can run out of virtual address space long before you run out of physical RAM. For example, by default, a 32-bit application on 32-bit windows can only spawn about 2000 threads - even though each of those only takes around 4 kiB of your RAM, they also take around 1 MiB of your address space. Of course, you don't want 2000 threads anyway, but there are other places to take up address space without requiring RAM (and not just by using a paging file).

Comment: Note that in practice you can only use 2-3 GB of address space in a 32 bit application, since part of the 4 GiB is reserved for the kernel.

Comment: @nwp: ah ok. I understand what you mean. I fixed it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: That's only if the kernel doesn't claim a virtual address space of its own. You clearly see this on 64 bits OS'es running a 32 bits application, where the virtual address space of the process is the wrong size for the kernel. That means there's only a small interfacing stub in the 32 bits address space, leaving 3.5+ GB for the application.

Answer (score 9):

Unless you want to go back to the old days of memory paging (remember those 16 bit Z80 machines in the 1980s with 128k RAM), or early DOS expanded memory, then you need more than a 32 bit pointer to address all the available memory on a modern machine.

A 64 bit pointer is a natural (though not a necessary) choice for a 64 bit architecture.

Note that pointers of different types **do not** have to be the same size: `sizeof(double*)` does not **necessarily** have to be the same as `sizeof(int*)`, for example.

Comment: Z80 and such would have a 16-bit address range.

Comment: Amended. I remember those days well; lovingly!

Comment: Of course, there's also been tricks like PAE, that allowed addressing more than 4 GiB on a 32-bit system. However, 64-bit is vastly simpler, and it gives you effectively infinite address space (for the moment; we'll see how that still holds up in a hundred years :D).

Comment: We still have memory paging today! The difference is that the support is now transparent to applications, but the OS still has to initialize page tables.

Comment: Are there any examples of systems where pointers to different types have a different size?

Comment: @Ferruccio I'm curious about that too. Even though I've been programming in many different environments for 35 years now, I never encountered any system that mixed different size pointers in 1 program. (Different pointer sizes in one OS is certainly possible: E.g 64-bit Windows having a 32-bit sub-system so you can encounter both sizes, but not in a single program. Those sub-systems are effectively another program even if you can call a 32-bit component from a 64-bit program.)

Comment: @Luaan memory paging (say expanded memory on DOS) is different to PAE. The former can be used to give more virtual memory to a single process, while the later allows the kernel to handle more physical memory (every single process will still be limited by the normal 32bit rules). Two pair of shoes.

Comment: @Tonny You mean you never noticed it. That or you never programmed in C++, because the standard implementation for pointers to member functions (using adjustor thunks) means that those pointers can have varying sizes in a single program. Or more classical there were far and near pointers back in the good old days.

Comment: @Voo I do C++, but never had a reason to delve that deeply in the technicalities of the generated code. I'll take your word for it. As for the olden days (note I don't call them "good") of far and near pointers... I wouldn't call those real pointers. They were a very ugly kludge to circumvent the 16-bit index to more than 16-bit addressable memory problem. And usually you wouldn't mix them in the same program. Lucky for me I worked mostly on Unix and Aix systems in the 80's and 90's that already had true 32-bit CPU's and pointers (MC680x0, MIPS and PowerPC).

Comment: @Tonny While selectors certainly didn't make for a particularly nice programming model, to the best of my knowledge the correct technical term was still "far pointer" (what else would you call them?). And if you had more than one module you needed far pointers, so yes you would mix them (well use both kinds in one application) if you wanted say use the clipboard.

Comment: @Voo Given your reference to the clipboard I presume you mean in 16-bit Windows code? I didn't get into Windows programming until the late 90's on Windows 95/98. Anything I wrote then was already real 32-bit, so I never got much exposure to 16-bit environments. What little I recall from those days (it's been a while) if you really needed this you just declared everything "far" and let the compiler sort it out. (My recollection is probably not entirely correct :-)

Comment: @Tonny Mixing different sized pointers was common in DOS programs that used larger amounts of memory.  Note only NEAR vs FAR calls for code, but NEAR vs FAR data segments (not to mention HUGE "segments").

Comment: @MSalters Actually, that's just a reuse of the same name for a different concept. Old-school paging was about manually selecting memory segments, while modern paging means that memory is *allocated* (or reserved) in distinct pages. Modern paging uses a flat memory model on the instruction level - as you say, it's transparent. But on the CPU-level, OS-level and application-level, it handles completely differently.

Comment: @Tonny, "real" pointers they are; just not simple.  Farther back, the IBM 360 architecture had a selector and offset fields inside one pointer value, and that was the fundamental pointer used by all such instructions.

Comment: @Tonny I could provide examples of OSes and hardware where pointers to different types had different sizes. In particular, pointers to functions often were of a different size than pointers to data types.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the other answers, it is natural to have a pointer type that can uniformly and seamlessly indicate an arbitrary location in the memory.

Now if you have a complicated data structure that uses small objects and pointers between them (like a graph, a tree), the memory taken by the pointers will be doubled when you compile in 64 bits, which is a drawback (and this is probably why you asked the question).

Note that all these data structures (graph, tree, hash map, etc...) can also be implemented in contiguous arrays in memory, and accessed through indices (it is how FORTRAN programmers implement them for instance), and if you know in advance that you have less than 4 billion elements, then you can represent your indices as 32 bit integers, even when you compile in 64 bits mode (this is what I'm doing for a 3D mesh modeling software).